Transferring a File from Google Cloud Compute Instance to Your Personal Google Drive Account
I extensively use Google Cloud Compute Engine for numerical simulations in my research. These simulations generate large output files, which I need to download to a local machine as compressed files for analysis. Due to frequent travel, I split my time between North America and India. Consequently, I chose to attach the compute instance to the "us-central" region. However, downloading large files from the compute instance to my local machine via scp is extremely slow when I'm in India, despite having a high-speed internet connection (~300 MiB/s). The download speeds are often below 100 KiB/s.
To address this issue, I aim to:

Transfer the files to my personal Google Drive account.
Download the files from Google Drive to my local machine using gcloud compute scp, as regular downloads from Google Drive are only limited by my internet connection speed.

Could someone help me with step (1)?

download file from cloud upload it to your local machine and then upload it to drive. there is no way to go directly from cloud to drive.   It still going to land in memory on your machine.
